# Max Length error while using Huggingface Transformer model for SHAP Explanation

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, shap, summarization, xai

I am using SHAP Explanation to explain the output of the pretrained model. It works for the documents with the token length less than 1024. It throws an error below if I provide sequence with token length more than 1024.
The script that I used for generating explanation is as follows.

```
!pip install transformers[sentencepiece] datasets sacrebleu rouge_score py7zr -q    
import numpy as np

import torch
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer

import shap

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sshleifer/distilbart-xsum-12-6")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("sshleifer/distilbart-xsum-12-6").cuda()
dataset = load_dataset("xsum", split="train")
s = dataset["document"][2:3]
explainer = shap.Explainer(model, tokenizer)
shap_values = explainer(s)
```

It throws the error below.

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1196 > 1024). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
You have modified the pretrained model configuration to control generation. This is a deprecated strategy to control generation and will be removed soon, in a future version. Please use and modify the model generation configuration (see https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies#default-text-generation-configuration )
```

Comment: The model you are using only supports up to 1024 tokens. You could try to work with a sliding window approach.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I am a beginner using huggingface. Can u please provide a sample of how can i use sliding window in my approach. Would be very helpful

Comment: Like how can I change the tokenizer to support sliding window and then pass it to the SHAP explanation.

Comment: Just check this answer (I won't post it here, because it would be a duplicate): [How can I handle overflowing tokens in Huggingface Transformer model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76342339/how-can-i-handle-overflowing-tokens-in-huggingface-transformer-model). You will also need the decode function to convert the windows back to strings.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. The shap Explainer only accepts the pipeline of the model/ model, tokenizer as input. How can i add these windowed input in SHAP Explanation.

Comment: As I said, convert them back to strings with decode (which is also shown in the other answer).

Comment: It throws the same error again. Here is the link to the script. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Xwab_J-bN8cCDgQatYEJcRYSAXmitWUT?usp=sharing

Comment: Your solution to answer of dividing large length inputs in windows worked amazingly. But while feeding this decoded input in shap explainer it again throws the same error of maximum length. Is there any way i can resolve this