# What does this mean? "Be aware, overflowing tokens are not returned for the setting you have chosen"

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I don't understand if this is an error or warning:

> Be aware, that overflowing tokens are not returned for the setting you have chosen, i.e. sequence pairs with the 'longest_first' truncation strategy. So the returned list will always be empty even if some tokens have been removed.

This is a minimal example code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification

# Set device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Load tokenizer and model
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased").to(device)

# Load dataset
dataset = load_dataset("glue", "mnli")
val_loader = DataLoader(dataset["validation_matched"], batch_size=64)

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
for epoch in range(10):
    model.eval()
    total_correct = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in val_loader:
            inputs = tokenizer(batch["premise"], batch["hypothesis"], padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=128, return_tensors="pt")
            inputs = {key: value.to(device) for key, value in inputs.items()}
            labels = batch["label"].to(device)

            outputs = model(**inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs.logits, labels)

            total_correct += (outputs.logits.argmax(dim=1) == labels).sum().item()

    val_accuracy = total_correct / len(dataset["validation_matched"])

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: Val Acc: {val_accuracy:.4f}")
```

Do I need to change something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I handle overflowing tokens in Huggingface Transformer model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76342339/how-can-i-handle-overflowing-tokens-in-huggingface-transformer-model)

Comment: @cronoik No, because it depends on several factors and I was on many of such links. Besides model and depends on the dataset and how u use the tokenizer, such as `tokenizer.encode` or `tokenizer.encode_plus`.

Comment: As far as I can follow you, none of the mentioned points matters. You want to perform sequence classification and some of your texts are longer than the specified 128. The question that you need to answer is if a returned truncated sequence contains enough information to predict the label. In case the answer is `no`, you need to deal with the overflowing tokens in some way.